# Emacs Tramp Mode stucks while working with Compilation Mode

Tags: emacs, tramp

I use Tramp Mode + Compilation Mode for editing and compiling code on a remote machine.

However, when compilation meets error, Emacs always stucks until C-g.

Message buffer shows error like:

```
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 2424) signaled (quit)
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 3027) signaled (quit)
QuitError during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 3467) signaled (quit)
```

I'm not quite sure whether it is a problem of Tramp Mode, or Compilation Mode.

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911))

Tramp version: 2.3

Comment: Hard to say where the error comes from. Doesn't look like Tramp, but who knows. Does the error happen also when you start `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus It still happens when start with `emacs -Q`

Comment: This will need more debugging. Not covered by stackoverflow.. Pls write a bug report against Emacs.